# Why does the splice item return to the display upon the next list entry?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, splice

I looked at all of the previous relevant questions, and nothing helped, so here I am.

The user can add list items to a global variable one at a time, or copy/paste with commas between each list item.
Good to go on that part I think. It works anyhow. So does the delete list item.

The problem is when the next item is entered on the list after deleting one, it will also put the deleted item on back on the list.

Here is my code snippet and code pen. Please help me learn what is wrong.

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/gatehrdy/pen/gdvKgP)

```
function deleteListItem(){
    var listToSearch = $('#displayArea').html().split(', ');
    var searchItem = prompt('item to delete').trim();
    var res = listToSearch.indexOf(searchItem);
    if(searchItem !== '' && res !== -1){
        listToSearch.splice(res, 1);
        $('#displayArea').html(listToSearch.join(', '));
    }else{
        alert('Please enter search name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you work with text from `$('#displayArea')`. But there's `listInputArr` variable in your code which stores list of items, but in your function you don't change it. So, instead of getting items from a string, get items from `listInputArr` and delete item there:

```
var searchItem = prompt('item to delete').trim();
var res = listInputArr.indexOf(searchItem);
if(searchItem !== '' && res !== -1){
  listInputArr.splice(res, 1);
  $('#displayArea').html(listInputArr.join(', '));
}else{
  alert('Please enter search name');
}
```

Comment: @codeForger have a look at my answer. I've fixed what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating listToSearch (local variable) and displayArea (html element), but not you global variable listInputArr. Make sure you delete the element from listInputArr in deleteListItem().

```
function deleteListItem(){
  var searchItem = prompt('item to delete').trim();
  var res = listInputArr.indexOf(searchItem);
  if(searchItem !== '' && res !== -1){
    listInputArr.splice(res, 1);
    $('#displayArea').html(listInputArr.join(', '));
  }else{
    alert('Please enter search name');
  }

}
```

Comment: I have tried to splice the item from the listInputArr as well. It doesnt seem to work. for some reason, i dont think the variable of the users input to delete is getting assigned to the variable, or the indexOf function is not working.

Comment: I added the fixed delete method in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I modified some of your code and it seemed to work.
In your inputFunc() change `listInputArr.push(userItem);` to

```
listInputArr.push(...userItem.split(','));
```

This will make sure that if user enter 'aa, bb' it is not stored as a single string, but split into separated strings on ','

next you need to change you deleteListItem() as follows:

```
function deleteListItem(){
  //var listToSearch = $('#displayArea').html().split(', ');
  var searchItem = prompt('item to delete').trim();
  var res = listInputArr.indexOf(searchItem);
  alert(res);
  if(searchItem !== '' && res !== -1){
    listInputArr.splice(res, 1);
  $('#displayArea').html(listInputArr.join(', '));
  }else{
    alert('Please enter search name');
  }
}
```

I hope this help. Please let me know if you encounter an issue with my code.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine with the above code in my fork of your code. check here: https://codepen.io/ashishpatelmedia/pen/EeELrw?editors=0010, there seems no issue like mentioned in your question. Let me know if you find the issue in my fork.

Comment: @codeForger It's working. I see no issue as mentioned in your question.

Comment: Ashish Patel The problem only happens when the list is pasted in with multiple list items at the same time. If the user types in one name at a time, then the delete function works great. Im trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @codeForger if you wish to delete more than one item at once, you can loop through the user inputs and delete them one by one inside the delete function.